# Microscopic Point Defects Interaction with Dislocation Motion

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science

I am currently studying material science and we had been going through strengthening lately. One thing I never thoroughly understand is how exactly does point defects such as vacancies and interstitial defects relates with dislocation motion. On macroscopic scale, it is visible that the dislocation motion is halted by the point defect. However, microscopically, how do they interact? Why does strained bonds reduces dislocation motions?

Comment: Review the concept of the [Cottrell atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottrell_atmosphere), for example. Replacing an atom with a vacancy can be energetically favorable in a region under compressive stress, and inserting an interstitial can be favorable in a region under tensile stress. These defects, if unlikely to move, can pin a dislocation in place. This should give some useful terms for further searches.